# Current transformer to DAQ

Tags: transformer, current-measurement, current-transformer, daq

I'm using a [MCC 128 HAT DAQ](https://www.mccdaq.com/PDFs/specs/DS-MCC-128.pdf) on top of a Raspberry Pi. I'm reading the output from an [AT-50-B10 current transformer](https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/at-b10.pdf) that's around the mains cable (UK) that's powering the Pi & monitor.

[image]

I'm measuring roughly ±7V using 8kHz sampling rate.

[image]

So what am I seeing here? The AT data sheet says it gives an a voltage between 0-10V (scaled between 0-50A) proportional to the RMS of the current in the primary. There's no way I'm pulling 35 amps!

Have I wired this up correctly?

Schematic:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: That's a slightly distorted sine wave with about 5 V RMS, which would scale to 25 A RMS. But the datasheet indicates it should be 0-10 VDC. So something's not right. It's hard to tell how it's hooked up. Check the output of the CT with a voltmeter. And test the input of the data acquisition device to see what it reads with a known voltage, like a 1.5 V or 9 V battery.

Comment: If you clamp it around a cable containing both neutral and live, the currents cancels and you should read zero. This isn't your problem at the moment, but once you figured out where the +-7 V comes from, and fix that, this comes next in order to be able to measure current.

Comment: @PStechPaul just put 6 VDC from a bench power supply into the DAQ & got 6 VAC. Just connecting the wires from the power supply without turning the supply on & I got 2 VAC

Comment: It sounds like you have external mains power interference, noise pickup, or a grounding problem. It might be better to use a battery to eliminate AC noise from the power supply. Draw a sketch of exactly how you have everything connected.

Comment: @PStechPaul sketch added to OP

Comment: @PStechPaul thanks, it was a missing common ground between the -ve terminal of the CT & the -ve terminal of the DAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the +/-7V when there is no load?  (wire passes through but no load on the end)
CTs need a load resistor.  I don't see and information on the data sheet. Maybe there is a resistor inside but many don't have one and it must be added.

You need to have just the hot wire pass through the TC  (or the neutral) but not both!